# ByteBuddy Pipe.Binder fails with java 8 Function

Tags: java, bytecode, byte-buddy

The [documentation](http://bytebuddy.net/#members) on ByteBuddy for using a `Pipe` annotation with method delegation states that `java.util.function.Function` is a suitable type to be bound for use with `Pipe`.

> The @Pipe annotation is not preregistered with the MethodDelegation
>   because the Java class library does not come with a suitable interface
>   type before Java 8 which defines the Function type.

However, when I actually use it (in java 8), an exception is thrown, which appears to be caused by the default methods on `Function`.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: interface java.util.function.Function must declare exactly one non-static method
    at net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Pipe$Binder.onlyMethod(Pipe.java:164)
    at net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Pipe$Binder.install(Pipe.java:145)
    at net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Pipe$Binder.install(Pipe.java:131)
```

Here is the binding code:

```
builder.implement(Proxy.class)
       .method(ElementMatchers.any())
       .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(ProxyClassImpl.class)
                                  .appendParameterBinder(Pipe.Binder.install(Function.class)));
```

It appears that the issue might be that `Pipe.Binder.install` is looking for all methods which are not static. Perhaps it should exclude default methods also.

Additionally, I tried this with `com.google.common.base.Function` and got a similar failure because it declares the `equals` method overridden from `Object`. So perhaps any methods which exist on `Object` should also be excluded when trying to identify the single method to pipe through.

Comment: Can you compile java 8 code? Say a main with `Function<String, String> f = s -> s;` ?

Comment: @assylias Yes. The code compiles just fine. The problem is not that Function cannot be found. It is that ByteBuddy does not appear to actually like the methods declared on the Function interface despite the documentation indicating it can be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You found a bug in the library that I have introduced in a recent version. This is not supposed to happen and it will be fixed in version 1.1.1 that I release today. Thank you for reporting.

Comment: Should I have logged this as a github issue instead?

Comment: You could have since this is more of a bug report than a general question but it does not really matter to me as long as I notice the question.